# Computer not booting after hard drive disconnect

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, multi-boot

I have four drives in my computer

- 500 GB HDD ext4 for data
- 2 TB HDD ntfs for data
- 250 GB SSD with debian linux
- 128 GB SSD with windows7

I have windows installed first and later installed debian on the other drive.

Grub contains a seperate boot record for windows7

Yesterday I disconnected all drives to work on anothee driver. After reconnecting my drives I can't boot at all.

It seems like the debian boot option got lost.

Booting from the debian SSD results in an error that asks me to insert a proper boot media.

Booting from the windows SSD seems to work first but resets with a blue screen while booting.

How can I restore the boot record? 
I don't want to reinstall everything!

Comment: Are the drives connected to the same ports as before? Check if grub is configured to boot off of a specific port and connect the drives like they were before.

Comment: The drives are connected to the same ports as they used to be. I don't have any access to grub since the system does not boot. I thing that Linux may created it's own boot entry on bios level that got lost when the drives could not been found.

Comment: have you, by any chance, changed the controller settings in the BIOS? I know Windows will crash, if the controller is set to RAID mode; it looks like it's gonna work, but it just BSODs.

Comment: No I did not change anything in the bios affecting the controller settings. Note that I used to boot windows from a boot entry inside grub and not directly from the bios boot menu.

Comment: I'm sorry but I did  change the controller from ADHCI to IDE after switcching it back I can at least boot windows. However Linux is still not booting

Comment: I'm not the kind of person that can fix Linux boot problems, but I'm glad at least *one* OS is working.